# Xarray write large dataset on memory without killing the kernel

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray, zarr

**Context:**
I have the following dataset:
[image: dataset]

**Goal:** I want to *write* it on my disk. I am using chunks so the dataset does not kill my kernel.

**Problem:**
I tried to save it on my disk with chunks using:

1. Option 1: `to_zarr` -> biggest homogeneous chunks possible: `{'mid_date':41, 'x':379, 'y':1}`
2. Option 2: `to_netcdf` -> chunk size `{'mid_date':3000, 'x':758, 'y':617}`
3. Option 3: `to_netcdf` (or `to_zarr`, same result) -> chunk size `{'mid_date':1, 'x':100, 'y':100}`

But the memory ends up blowing anyway (and I have 96Gb of RAM). Option 3 tries another approach by saving chunk by chunk, but it still blows up the memory (*see screenshot*). Moreover, it strangely seems to take longer and longer to process chunks as they are written on disk. Do you have a suggestion on how I could solve this problem ?

In the screenshot, I would be expecting 1 line of `#` per file, but on Chunk 2 already, it seems it's saving multiple chunks at once (3 lines of `#`). The size of chunk 2 was `502kb`.
[image]

**Code:**

```
import xarray as xr
import os
import sys
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import numpy as np

xrds = #massive dataset
pathsave = 'Datacubes/'


#Option 1, did not work
#write_job = xrds.to_zarr(f"{pathsave}Test.zarr", mode='w', compute=False, consolidated=True)

#Option 2, did not work (with chunk size {'mid_date':3000, 'x':100, 'y':100})


#write_job = xrds.to_netcdf(f"test.nc",compute=False)
#with ProgressBar():
#    print(f"Writing to {pathsave}")
#    write_job = write_job.compute()                 

# Option 3, did not work. That's the option I took the screenshot from
# I force the chunks to be really small so I don't overload the memory
chunk_size = {'mid_date':1, 'y':xrds.y.shape[0], 'x':xrds.x.shape[0]}

with ProgressBar():
    for i, (key, chunk) in enumerate(xrds.chunk(chunk_size).items()):
        chunk_dataset = xr.Dataset({key: chunk})
        chunk_dataset.to_netcdf(f"{pathsave}/chunk_{i}.nc", mode="w", compute=True)
        print(f"Chunk {i+1} saved.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a very large number of chunks in the dataset, so probably what's filling up memory is the graph itself. I recommend passing `chunks={...}` when opening the xarray object with the chunksize an integer factor of the default size you are using, such that the number of chunks is at least a factor of 10 smaller than it is now. That will also make for better performance when accessing the data in the zarr store later.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not enough, it still crashed the kernel.
So if I understand well there isn't any workaround that ?